# Running supervisord in a non root container

Tags: docker, supervisord

I'm pretty convinced that your container should as few privileges as possible.
So I'm trying to do so in the containers I'm working on.

That said how do you handle a supervisord process in your container when non root ? Is it only possible ?

My Dockerfile

```
FROM        php:apache

#ARG         USER_ID
#ARG         GROUP_ID

RUN     apt-get update -y && \
        apt-get install -yqq supervisor && \
        rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*;

# creating appropriate user
#RUN         addgroup --gid $GROUP_ID dockeruser
#RUN         adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' --uid $USER_ID --gid $GROUP_ID dockeruser

COPY        ./run-on-start.sh /etc/init.d/run-on-start.sh

CMD     ["/etc/init.d/run-on-start.sh"]

#USER        dockeruser
```

```bash
#! /bin/sh

# running supervisor to process the queue
/usr/bin/supervisord

# running apache process
exec apache2-foreground
```

I commented the part to set specific userid in order to test supervisor is starting on docker run.
If you have one solution I would be happy.

Answer (score 0):

as long as supervisord and its services can run with same owner -- after tweaking some defaults (e.g. placing pid/sock/logs/temp files in some directory writable by this non-root user) you can do it and it works ok